# I upgraded and the old wallpapers gone, how can I get them back?

Tags: upgrade, appearance

I upgraded to natty and the old background images are gone. How do I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wallpapers, or backgrounds, for maverick are listed here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-art-pkg/ubuntu-wallpapers/ubuntu/files/56

You can download the jpg's one at a time.  If you want to download them all at once you can go to this page and download the ubuntu-wallpapers-*-tar.gz file

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/maverick/ubuntu-wallpapers

Unzip the file (gzip -d ubuntu-wall*gz), and untar it (tar xf ubuntu-wall*gz).  The images will all be in a directory.

Get the image you want by either method.

Then right-click on your desktop, choose "Change Desktop Background", then click "Add" and choose the image you want as your background.  It should now be your new background.

Comment: thanks, that works. But, it still seems like an odd thing for a user to update and have stuff disappear that you liked.

Answer (score 1):

You can get old (and current) stock wallpapers [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-wallpapers&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all). Download the deb matching the release you want, but save them, **don't open them in software center**. After downloading them, right-click the file and pick *Open with Archive Manager*. Browse the package and extract the wallpapers you want.